# Ubuntu 17.10 not booting up anymore

Tags: boot, 17.10, systemd-logind

I upgraded Ubuntu to 17.10 a few days ago and everything worked. Now without apparent reason (probably due to some recent updates) the system won't boot up anymore.

If I remove "quiet splash" from the bootoptions get error messages like:

> Failed to start Bluetooth service
>
> Failed to start Thermal Daemon service
>
> Failed to start Login service
>
> Failed to start Accounts service
>
> Failed to start Modem Manager
>
> Failed to start Network Manager
>
> Dependend Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online

By Starting into the root console with the grub option  "1" and doing
systemctl start systemd-logind.service
I got an errormessage about dbus saying something about the "power" group.

Using a previous kernel doesn't change anything about the errors.

Basically I'm stuck at the root console without networking.....

Comment: It seems my package apport is broken, and I have this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1745033

However I do not know if this is the cause of my bootproblem.

Comment: and when I do "dpkg-reconfigure dbus"  I get a segmentation fault....

Comment: and reinstalling i also get a segmentation fault.... awesome....  I'm really getting tired of this...

Comment: somehow the dpkg-reconfigure fails with every package... either dpkg is broken or something that does the post/pre removal/install script is broken....

Comment: Everything works again. I solved it by doing chroot in a live cd: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/chroot/Live-CD/  
and then reinstalling all kinds of packages  with aptitude until there were no errors left.